# How to extract values from multiple lists coming from several json pages

Tags: r

I'm trying to extract the "title" and "id" of movies coming from json content from several pages. This is the piece of code I use for making the request:

```
themoviedb_ip_address <- "https://api.themoviedb.org"
themovidedb_discover_movie_url <- "/3/discover/movie"

pages <- c(1,2)

themovidedb_discover_movie_req <- paste(themoviedb_ip_address,
                                        themovidedb_discover_movie_url,
                                        "?",
                                        api_key,"&sort_by=revenue.desc",
                                        "&include_adult=false",
                                        "&include_video=false",
                                        "&page=",
                                        "{pages}",
                                        "&primary_release_year=2010",
                                        "&with_genres=18",
                                        sep = "")

movie_revenue_2010 <- str_glue(themovidedb_discover_movie_req) %>%
  map(GET) %>%
  map(content,as = "parsed") %>%
  map(purrr::pluck, "results")
```

This gives me the following result:

[image]

and

[image]

When trying to extract the titles and ids with the following piece of code:

```
movie_revenue_2010 <- str_glue(themovidedb_discover_movie_req) %>%
  map(GET) %>%
  map(content,as = "parsed") %>%
  map(purrr::pluck, "results") %>% 
  map_df(magrittr::extract, c("title", "id"))
```

I get the following error: Error: Argument 1 must have names

Please note that the following piece of code works correctly:

```
for(i in 1:2){

  themovidedb_discover_movie_query_string <- paste("&sort_by=revenue.desc",
                                                   "&include_adult=false",
                                                   "&include_video=false",
                                                   "&page=",
                                                   i,
                                                   "&primary_release_year=2010",
                                                   "&with_genres=18",
                                                   sep = "")

  #print(themovidedb_discover_movie_query_string)

  movie_revenue_2010_req <-
    httr::GET(paste(themoviedb_ip_address,
                    themovidedb_discover_movie_url,
                    "?",
                    api_key,
                    themovidedb_discover_movie_query_string,
                    sep = ""))

  movie_revenue_2010_content <- httr::content(movie_revenue_2010_req,
                                              as = "parsed")

  movie_revenue_2010 <- purrr::pluck(movie_revenue_2010_content, "results")
  movie_revenue_2010_tbl <- movie_revenue_2010_tbl %>%
    bind_rows(map_df(movie_revenue_2010, extract, c("title", "id")))
}
```

But I can't use "for loop" in my work.

A dput() of the content is available here:

```
movie_revenue_2010 <- str_glue(themovidedb_discover_movie_req) %>%
  map(GET) %>%
  map(content,as = "parsed") %>%
  map(purrr::pluck, "results") %>%
  dput()
```

[dput()](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14zYU7-zC1Z0Z5yhLSoZM60Y0xidZ4Njn/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example of your data using `dput` ?

Comment: I updated the description with the dput() content.

Comment: Can you check if running this part `map_df(magrittr::extract, c("title", "id"))` with `map` instead produces a result? if yes, then you have `NA` produced in some of the results which leads to this error.

Comment: Using map instead of map_df gives me the following result: list(list(NULL, NULL), list(NULL, NULL))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your nested list is called `temp`, we can do

```
library(purrr)
map(temp, ~map_df(.x, `[`, c('title', 'id')))

#[[1]]
# A tibble: 20 x 2
#   title                              id
#   <chr>                           <int>
# 1 The Twilight Saga: Eclipse      24021
# 2 The King's Speech               45269
# 3 The Karate Kid                  38575
# 4 Black Swan                      44214
# 5 Robin Hood                      20662
#...
#...

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 20 x 2
#   title                                                 id
#   <chr>                                              <int>
# 1 The Other Woman                                    52505
# 2 Green Zone                                         22972
# 3 The Fighter                                        45317
# 4 Burlesque                                          42297
# 5 Letters to Juliet                                  37056
#...
```

Or if you want everything in one dataframe

```
map_df(temp, ~map_df(.x, `[`, c('title', 'id')))

# A tibble: 40 x 2
#   title                         id
#   <chr>                      <int>
# 1 The Twilight Saga: Eclipse 24021
# 2 The King's Speech          45269
# 3 The Karate Kid             38575
# 4 Black Swan                 44214
# 5 Robin Hood                 20662
# 6 Shutter Island             11324
# 7 Sex and the City 2         37786
# 8 True Grit                  44264
# 9 The Social Network         37799
#10 The Sorcerer's Apprentice  27022
# … with 30 more rows
```

---

In base R, we can do

```
lapply(temp, function(x) do.call(rbind, lapply(x, `[`, c('title', 'id'))))
```

and

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(temp, function(x) do.call(rbind,lapply(x, `[`, c('title', 'id')))))
```

respectively for the same output as above.